# undefined error when adding form tags

Tags: javascript, html

I am using below code to change the image shown. When i add form tags to the html, i get an error in IE only where it says 'paint is undefined' when i change a drop down. I have spent ages searching and try to figure it out but no luck. Any ideas? Tks

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function callAFunction(SelectBox)
    {
        var caption=[
            'Default Image Caption',
            'Caption1',
            'Caption2',
            'Caption3',
            'Caption4',
            'Caption5',
            'Caption6',
            'Caption7',
            'Caption8',
            'Caption9'],
        bp='images/',
        imgnum=8,
        thumb=document.getElementById('thumb'),
        description=document.getElementById('caption');
        thumb.src=bp+'picture'+paint.value+vinyl.value+'.jpg';
        description.innerHTML=caption[SelectBox.value];
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>


<form>
<img src="images/picture1.jpg" alt="" id="thumb">

<div id="caption">Caption1</div>

<label>Change the Paint: </label>
<select id="paint" name="paint" onChange="callAFunction(this); return false;">
    <option value="1">Image 1</option>
    <option value="2">Image 2</option>
    <option value="3">Image 3</option>
    <option value="4">Image 4</option>
    <option value="5">Image 5</option>
    <option value="6">Image 6</option>
    <option value="7">Image 7</option>
    <option value="8">Image 8</option>
    <option value="9">Image 9</option>
</select><br />

<label>Change the Vinyl: </label>
<select id="vinyl" name="vinyl" onChange="callAFunction(this); return false;">
    <option value="1">Image 1</option>
    <option value="2">Image 2</option>
    <option value="3">Image 3</option>
    <option value="4">Image 4</option>
    <option value="5">Image 5</option>
    <option value="6">Image 6</option>
    <option value="7">Image 7</option>
    <option value="8">Image 8</option>
    <option value="9">Image 9</option>
</select>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you have used `paint.value` but you didn't defined it. Please defined it and try again.

Comment: add `paint=document.getElementById('paint');`

Answer (score 1):

`paint.value`  does not exist. Use `document.getElementById("paint").value` instead. Same for `vinyl.value`.

Comment: Ok will give it a go - why would it work in other browsers but not ie

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
paint[paint.selectedIndex].value
```